# delete Ubuntu from OS choice menu

Tags: 12.04, boot, windows-7, delete

I deleted Ubuntu from my laptop. Now I am working on Windows 7. However, when I turn on my laptop choice of ubuntu still appears in OS choice menu.

*How to delete choice of ubuntu from OS choice menu?*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Windows.

Comment: depends if it is using Grub or the windows loader... What does the screen look like? Also what windows version (look up "Fix MBR")

Answer (score 2):

Try using the tool [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: this tool is for ubuntu. I wrote that I am working on Windows 7. My Ubuntu doesn't work further

Comment: Well, then this question should belong on a windows forum. I would suggest you look into windows alternatives of this tool.